# Using Rxjs distinct operator to compare whole object with nesting

Tags: json, angular, object, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm having an observable that passes me a json object on which I'm using the distinct operator. 
I don't want to have duplicates if the entire object is same as before. I can't just use a one comparator like id, as it's id might be same but it's content not.

So I'm currenty stringifying the object and then using distinct and it works fine

Is there a better way to do this?

```
someObservable
  .startWith(cachedCopy)
  .map(item => JSON.stringify(item))
  .distinct()
  .subscribe(item => {
      //I do some stuff!
     })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think using `JSON.stringify()` to compare whether two objects contain the same data is the easiest way to go. If you know the object identity must be different you could use `pairwise().filter(pair => pair[0] !== pair[1])` (these must be two different object instances) but this really depends on your use-case and if you can guarantee such condition (usually not in my personal experience and comparing JSONs is "good enough").

Be aware that `distinct()` passes only really distinct items since the chain was created but in your description you say *"duplicates if the entire object is same as before"* which seems like you should be using `distinctUntilChanged` instead.

The `distinctUntilChanged` operator takes as an optional parameter a comparator function that you can use to check if two objects are the same:

```
.distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => JSON.stringify(prev) === JSON.stringify(curr))
```

Comment: Stringify is not a good option, in fact it's a wrong one because it is not stable in the order of keys.

Comment: I would use something like lodash `isEqual` instead of stringify though

Comment: @IngoBürk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: @martin The answer there itself points out that the order is important and the comments correctly explain that object keys aren't ordered, so that link just proves my point. What am I missing? Using stringify just relies on browser implementation details that aren't guaranteed by the spec

Comment: did anyone find a solution?

Comment: I think stringify is the best option for the majority of simple cases. The number one reason (I think) for wanting to use `distinctUntilChanged` is to minimize unnecessarily running through an observable chain when the source hasn't effectively changed. If your source is the same I would be astonished if the order of keys were ever to change in this context. Unless you're sending data from one browser to another to compare - you're probably just needing to comparing two successive values from your own stream - in which case stringify is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

When you have lodash in your application anyway, you can simply utilize lodash's `isEqual()` function, which does a deep comparison and perfectly matches the signature of `distinctUntilChanged()`:

```
.distinctUntilChanged(isEqual),
```

Or if you have `_` available (which is not recommended anymore these days):

```
.distinctUntilChanged(_.isEqual),
```

Comment: Why isn't lodash recommenced anymore? The only downside that I'm aware of is bundle size, which can be remedies by using lodash-es (supports tree-shaking, so your code is no larger than it needs to be).

Comment: It's not lodash itself that's not recommended. It's using lodash via `_` that's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

instead I used Underscore.js Lib,it has a function  called unique really saved me
https://underscorejs.org/#uniq

1-install it :

```
$ npm install underscore
```

2- call it:

```
import { _ } from 'underscore';
```

3-use it:

```
this.allcate = _.uniq(this.allcate);
```

Comment: All this does it reorders an array. Are you saying you use this and then put it through stringify? Or something else. Also changing the order of an array I think qualifies as being a change, so you wouldn't actually want this in most cases.